# List of C type structures in Python won't keep values

Tags: python, arrays, structure

I am relatively new to python language. I am trying to develop an algorithm but I ma stuck into a problem managing C-like structures in my code.
The code looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint
from ctypes import *


class three(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("a", c_int),
        ("b", c_int),
        ("c", c_int),
    ]

test = [three for i in range(10)]

for i in range(10):
    test[i].a = randint(0,20)
    test[i].b = randint(0,20)
    test[i].c = randint(0,20)
    print test[i].c

print "-----------------TEST PRINT-------------------"
for i in range(10):
    print test[i].c
```

It is very simple, I create my structures, then I generate a list of them and assign to each field of each structure a random value between 0 and 20. 
Running this code results in the following results:

```
2
14
5
20
17
8
4
5
10
6
-----------------TEST PRINT-------------------
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
```

If I try to print the same vector right after, seems like I can just read out the last element.
What's happening here? Any clues about this? How are lists of structures best handled?

Thanks you in advance for your suggestions.
 Giovanni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run

```
test = [three for i in range(10)]
```

you are not creating 10 different objects, but passing the class `three` 10 times. To initialize an object you need to add `()`:

```
test = [three() for i in range(10)]
```

This will create 10 different objects of type `three`.

**Edit:**

When you are using `three.c` instead of `three().c` you are getting `three`'s `c` static variable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python/68672#68672)